# arrow function & setTimeout scope

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I'm following this tut on js: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajTvmGxWQF8&list=PL1PqvM2UQiMoGNTaxFMSK2cih633lpFKP&index=8

and in the part where he explains why not to use setTimeout with arrow functions, the justification is that they look for scope on the window. and not on the enclosed scope. But the tests i made, had the opposite results: the named functions had window, arrow function was the correct one. So:

```js
const dude = {
  name: 'dude',
  namedFunc() {
    console.log('name 1: ', this.name); // Dude

    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('this 1:', this);
      console.log('name 2:', this.name); // undefined
    }, 200);
  },
  arrowFunc() {
    console.log('name 3:', this.name); // Dude

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('this 2:', this); // {name: 'dude', nameWNamed: ƒ, nameWArrow: ƒ}

      console.log('name 4:', this.name); // Dude
    }, 300)
  }
}

console.log('namedFunc:', dude.namedFunc()); // Dude
console.log('arrowFunc:', dude.arrowFunc()); // Dude
```

Expected:

```
this 1: {name: 'dude', namedFunc: ƒ, arrowFunc: ƒ}
name 2: dude
this 2: Window {window: Window, self: Window, document: document, name: '', location: Location, …}
name 4:
```

Actual result:

```
this 1: Window {window: Window, self: Window, document: document, name: '', location: Location, …}
name 2: 
this 2: {name: 'dude', namedFunc: ƒ, arrowFunc: ƒ}
name 4: dude
```

Comment: I think you've misunderstood, he is not saying not to use `setTimeout()` with arrow functions, he's giving an example of when using an arrow function would be useful (ie: for callback functions inside of object methods). In the video he explains how the `this` refers to the value that `this` would have outside of the arrow function (ie: the value used in `talk`)

Comment: (sorry for late reply) 
yes, i get hes talking about pros & cons of using both. i just dont understand the discrepancy between my tests and his. And actually my tests wont match his entire explanation, given this inside setTimeout, inside arrow functions, would be === window